# Problems with the Transfer of "Umlaute" from Client to Server

Tags: javascript, jsp, netbeans, encoding, tomcat7

For a while now I am developing a JSP-System and fortunately I never had any bigger issues transferring the "Umlaute" such as 'ä', 'ö', 'ü' and 'ß'.
Now after a while I updated my NetBeans to Nightly Build 201311070001 (Together with a Tomcat 7.0.41) and suddenly everything is just messed up...
I am not sure if the problem occurred only because of the update but I have no other event in mind...

My HTML/JS looks like:

```
<button onclick="
alert(encodeURIComponent(document.getElementById('Comment').value)); 
window.location.href = '/Proj/filter/MB/CreateMB.jsp
?Num=' 
+ encodeURIComponent(document.getElementById('Num').value) 
+ '&amp;Comment=' 
+ encodeURIComponent(document.getElementById('Comment').value)">
Create New MB
</button>
```

To determine whether the Error occurs because of the JavaScript I added this alert(...).

Now I enter the following in the field:

> Test äöüß {çǘ]

(The last letters don't appear in German, but I'd like to test even the worst case)
The alert() returns something I might have expected (due to the encodeURIComponent):

> Test%20%C3%A4%C3%B6%C3%BC%C3%9F%20%7B%C3%A7%C7%98%5D

Now I debug the output on the Server:

> Test Ã¤Ã¶Ã¼Ã {Ã§Ç]

Quite obvious something went wrong... Usually the JSP should have encoded everything on its own. Of course this nonsense gets directly into the database...

A whole bunch of new encoding problems appeared as well. In the database I have the correct value:

> PÄ-Schnur

but my code

```
StringEscapeUtils.escapeHtml(d.getMethod())
```

returns

> PÃ?-Schnur

By now it worked, suddenly the behavior changed.
Of course most of the functionality is sourced out into Java-Beans still the jsp-files kept their:

```
<%@page contentType="text/html" pageEncoding="UTF-8"%>
```

As the IDE kept the same encoding:
[image]

I'm just unable to figure out where the problem is coming from. Either it is the new IDE or during the installation it might have affected the Tomcat-Server. Has someone made similar experiences? What can I do about it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, I don't want to call this a solution, but I have to admit it works. 
Also that I don't know how and why.

I just deinstalled NetBeans, deleted the Server and reinstalled it. I kept the old server configs archived, so if anyone is interested in solving this issue, I can deliver...

Answer (score 0):

Use this [simple JSP](http://wiki.apache.org/tomcat/FAQ/CharacterEncoding#Q4) from the Apache Tomcat FAQ to test your system. If it doesn't work something in your configuration is messed up. If it does work, use it as a starting point to add the additional functionality in your JSP to find out at what point things go wrong.

Comment: Weird. The Test-JSP works perfectly.
But I have never used the command
`request.setCharacterEncoding("UTF-8");`

But this doesn't seem to be the cause. There are no changes with or without it...

Comment: So start with test JSP and extend it step by step until it does what the failing JSP does and identify the point at which it goes wrong.

Comment: Seems to me the problem is caused by the JavaScript:
`var mydata = encodeURIComponent(document.getElementById('mydata').value);
                window.location.href = 'index.jsp?mydata='+mydata;`

As I use this code instead of the regular form-submit it starts to mess everything up.

Do you have any idea how and why? Usually the encodeURIComponent-function should take care of everything...